# How to build a simple UI in python that runs an already complete python code and displays results within the UI window itself rather than the console?

Tags: python, user-interface, output, wxpython, pysimplegui

I have already written a complete code in python but I only run it from the console and it display the results in console. I need help in building a simple UI that has a run button that will allow the code to run and display its results within the user interface window and not on the console. How do I go about this? I am still a python beginner. The already written code is for face detection and recognition.

Answer (score 1):

Example code to run external python script.

```py
import subprocess
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Button("RUN")],
    [sg.Output(size=(80, 20))],
]

window = sg.Window("Title", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "RUN":
        sp = subprocess.Popen("python myscript.py", shell=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=None)
        out, err = sp.communicate()
        if out:
            print(out.decode("utf-8"))
        if err:
            print(err.decode("utf-8"))

window.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was inquiring about.